# Use module defined constants in pythoncode block

Tags: python, c++, swig

My C code defines a constant, I'm trying to add python code (in a `pythoncode` block) that uses that constant, for some reason this doesn't work.

Demonstration `.i` file:

```
%module test
%{
// c code defines a static constant
static const int i=3;
%}

// declare the constant so that it shows up in the python module
static const int i;

%pythoncode %{
# try to use the constant in some python code
lookup={'i':i,}
%}
```

Here's the error:

```
[dave]$ python -c "import test"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 70, in <module>
    lookup={'i':i,}
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

If I comment out the `lookup` dictionary in the `pythoncode` block, everything works fine:

```
[dave]$ python -c "import test; print test.i"
3
```

so at least when I import the module the constant shows up.

How can I "see" the C-defined constants in my `pythoncode` block?

swig 2.0.4, python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adding additional Python code](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn42) states for `%pythoncode`:

> This code gets inserted in to the `.py` file created by SWIG.

So let's tail the generated `test.py`:

```
# try to use the constant in some python code
lookup={'i':i,}

# This file is compatible with both classic and new-style classes.

cvar = _test.cvar
i = cvar.i
```

The `%pythoncode` was inserted before `i` is defined. Since it's the first and only appearance, you might need to use `_test.cvar.i` directly instead:

```
%pythoncode %{
# try to use the constant in some python code
lookup={'i': _test.cvar.i,}
%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to defer referencing the variable until after the module completes loading, by using a function:

```
%pythoncode %{
def lookup( key ){
     mp={'i':i}
     return mp[key]
%}
```